# Kendo UI Window overlay opacity

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-window

How can I set overlay opacity with CSS. I tried  `.k-overlay { opacity:0.9; }` but it wont work. Can anyone help me? here I provide a simple [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/aJUBiwEn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.k-widget` would be a too broad selection. You can set the opacity for that very window once the window will be shown:

```
<script>
function onOpen() {
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#dialog").parent().css("opacity", 0.2); }, 10);
}

$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  modal: true,
  open: onOpen
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I try to use those method but it seem still not working. Any idea why? [new demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/asUGeRUP)

Comment: It seems that Kendo overrides the CSS. I've added a minimal timeout to make it work. It's not the first time I had to do this. I'd be glad to learn a better solution!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. one more question what if I want set the opacity outside the kendo window? it is possible?

Comment: Sure. Once the window is open, you can set the opacity with the known call `$("#dialog").parent().css("opacity", 0.2);`

Answer (score 1):

You could try `.k-overlay { opacity:0.9 !important; }` instead. That will override the setting which kendo applies directly to the overlay.

Comment: i try, but it will applied on all kendo ui that have overlay eg. like kendo.alert. I only want to set on this kendo.window only.